# sql statement to alter table using where condition

Tags: mysql, php

After successful payment, i need to update the database. there is a column named access which is blank by default. when the payment is succesful the column should be inserted with a value called "admin".

```
    <?php
    include("config.php");
    $user_email=$_SESSION['email'];
      $check_user="select * from users WHERE user_email='$user_email'";

      $run=mysqli_query($dbcon,$check_user);

    while($row = $run->fetch_assoc())
    {

     $access=$row['access'];


    }
```

i use the above code  to access the values in table using session.
so after successul payment,the column should be inserted with value admin where user email= session[email]. can anyone tell me the sql statement for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems You do not need to `select` this record by `mysqli_query`. Update it directly by executing the query like

```
UPDATE users 
SET access='admin' 
WHERE user_email='$user_email' 
  AND access IS NULL;
```

and check the amount of `$affected_rows` by the statement execution.

If it is 1 - everything OK.

If it is 0 - something wrong (invalid e-mail, field value was already set in past, some error, etc.).

If it is more than 1 - data damage is possible.

Comment: I assume that $affected_rows should be 1 iff (if and only if) user.user_email is `UNIQUE` (which it probably should be!).

Comment: @Vérace That's right. But the author binds e-mail field and **payment** process without additional conditions - it is difficult for me to imagine that the e-mail field is not unique in this case.